# Resetting the Authorization policies on run-time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to bring down the size of my JWT token which internally gets the claims by User Role. For that to happen I created policies with the name same as of the Claim name and set the `policy.RequireRole` property in my policy registration like this:

```
 public static IServiceCollection RegisterPolicies(this IServiceCollection services, IClaimApplication claimApplication)
        {

            var applicationClaim = new ApplicationClaim();

            services.AddAuthorization(async options =>
            {
                var ClaimList = await claimApplication.GetList(applicationClaim);
                foreach (var item in ClaimList)
                {
                    //Commented this code for Testing in development env:

                    //if (item.ClaimType == "Inventory.Get")

                    if (item.ClaimType == "some claim")
                    {

                        options.AddPolicy(item.ClaimCode, policy => policy.RequireRole("admin","test"));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.AddPolicy(item.ClaimCode, policy => policy.RequireClaim(item.ClaimCode));
                    }
                }
            });

            return services;
        }
```

this works fine as it brings down the token size, as now I only have to return user roles and I bind the policies with claims having some role from the database.

this call is registered through the database, but the problem is as this is policy is only registered on application startup, any addition to the claims for that user role won't take effect until the application startup.

I somehow need to dynamically reset some policy based upon the change in the database but had no luck finding something that might help me with this. can someone please point me in the right direction?

I can't make this use-case work with custom Policy Requirements either

Comment: Can you please share how are you enforcing this policies?

Comment: @MkrtichMazmanyan `options.AddPolicy` thing is doing that

Comment: It's not, you need to use either `Authorize` attribute or `AuthorizeFilter`.

Comment: @MkrtichMazmanyan I'm doing that, that's not m concern, I want to reset the policies, to let's say add more roles to require role attribute of the policy

Comment: take a look into custom [`AuthorizationHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authorization-handlers) for your policies, you can load roles dynamically in the handler and create dynamic policies.

Comment: @MkrtichMazmanyan yes, but once those policies have been added, you can't modify those policies. let's say I want to allow another role for a particular policy when I have updated for this in the database it won't update.

Comment: Can't you instead of multiple policies per role create one policy with custom handler that will do that dynamic role checking based on claims?

Comment: @MkrtichMazmanyan for that the least I can do is make a database call on every request that comes in, as I have to do it dynamically. and a DB call on every req is not acceptable